# TFS User Can't Save Updated Work Item State

Tags: tfs, transition

I have a user who is attempting to change the State of a TFS Change Request from Development to Testing but when he presses Save gets the following error:

`Save failed: The field 'Changed By' contains a value that is not in the list of supported values`

From what I can work out (please correct me if I'm wrong) Changed By relates to the History tab showing what has changed on the item.

So I've Exported the Work Item Types for our project, and opened the XML for Change Requests.  When I searched for Test the State is listed as this:

```
   <STATE value="Test">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
            <LISTITEM value="[project]\Contributors" />
          </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
```

And the Transition from Development to Test is as follows:

```
    <TRANSITION from="Development" to="Test">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Signed Off" />
        <REASON value="Executive Signed Off" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="System.ChangedBy">
          <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
            <LISTITEM value="[project]\Owners" />
          </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
          <REQUIRED />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

I have checked both groups ([project]\Owners and [project]\Contributors).  They are not a member of the Contributors group, but I checked another user who isn't having this issue and they are not either, so I think I can rule out that permissions group?   And the Owners group has them listed (albeit under the group for their team) so I think that is correct.

The Field called ChangedBy populates from the Owners group and the user appears in that list (when checked from another point).

What could be causing this save issue?  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that XML, that says that only people in the Contributors group can save a WI in the Test state.  If your user isn't a contributor that explains the error.

Try adding your user the Contributor group and try again.